# What's a word for someone who enjoys pleasure, travel, food, thrill for new things

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I’m looking for an adjective/ noun that describes a person who loves life, traveling, great food, always doing things which gets adrenaline kicking and is a always ready for attempting things for pleasure only

Answer (score 1):

I hope the word **sybarite** will satisfy the OP.

"Joe Bloggs is a sybarite. In his quest to enjoy all that life has to offer, he travels the world first-class, stays at grand five-star hotels and eats at the finest Michelin starred restaurants. Yes, he enjoys a sybaritic lifestyle".

**Sybarite (noun) & sybaritic (adjective):** A devotee of luxury and the sensual vices. (Collins Dictionary)

And then we have **hedonist** (noun) and **hedonistic** (adjective) as in, "Joe Bloggs is a **hedonist.** He enjoys a **hedonistic** lifestyle". (as described above).

**Hedonism:** Living and behaving in ways that mean you get as much pleasure out of life as possible, according to the belief that the most important thing in life is to enjoy yourself. (Cambridge Dictionary)

Answer (score 1):

It's not one word but the definition of 'bon vivant' seems to match your description well. From free-dictionary:

> Bon vivant: a person who lives luxuriously and enjoys good food and drink.

Comment: Yes, we may also add a variant of 'bon vivant' with 'bon viveur", a 'Franglais'  expression in BE to describe a "person who likes going to parties and other social occasions and who also enjoys good food and wine, etc.". (M-W)

Comment: To some extent it matches but don't you feel it creates up an image of someone who has tons of money to splurge as well.. but for someone who enjoys the worldly pleasures ; does things to get a kick ; lives in the moment and at the same time has a plan for life too; bit secretive about personal life;

Answer (score -1):

The noun Cosmopolite may help you here but it might not cover everything you've asked for. You can also use Cosmopolitan as the adjective and noun form.

Answer (score -1):

Two down-to-earth words for you:

*vivacious*

(Collins) "full of high spirits and animation; lively or vital"

*dynamic*

"2. (of a person) positive in attitude and full of energy and new ideas"

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/dynamic